# Using nested @import with parent selector

Tags: css, less

I would like to use the "&" parent selector in LESS in combination with a nested @import statement to override variable definitions within a specific scope. Consider the following files

style.less:

```
@import 'component-variables.less';
@import (multiple) 'component.less';


.@{contrastWrapperClass}, .@{contrastWrapperClass}&{

    @componentBackgroundColor:#00ff00;
    @import (multiple) 'component.less';
}
```

component-variables.less:

```
@contrastWrapperClass: componentContrast;
@componentBackgroundColor: #ff0000;
```

component.less:

```
.component {
  background-color: @componentBackgroundColor;
}
```

I would expect this to compile to

```
.component {

    background-color:#ff0000;
}

.componentContrast .component,
.componentContrast.component {

    background-color:#00ff000;
}
```

it actually compiles to:

```
.component {

    background-color:#ff0000;
}
    
.componentContrast .component,
.componentContrast .component {  

    background-color:#00ff000;
}
```

In this example, the goal would be to switch the background-color for any .component element that also has the "componentContrast" class or is a child of an element with the "componentContrast" class.